# SonarQube server does not start because of a Background initialization failure

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have just installed SonarQube server on my Windows 8 computer according to "Get Started in Two Minutes" instructions. I have the latest Java (jre1.8.0_131) on my machine. I got an error at startup in web.log. How can i fix that?

> 2017.07.17 05:24:33 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Custom Analyzer [ındex_words_analyzer] failed to find filter under name [word_filter]
>
> at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.CustomAnalyzerProvider.build(CustomAnalyzerProvider.java:76)

Comment: This is related to the Elasticsearch search engine. Did you configure anything special regarding search?

Comment: No, i did not. What am i supposed to do in order to make SonarQube work?

Comment: Which exact version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: I tried sonarqube-6.4 first, then tried sonarqube-5.6.6. Both versions generate the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new version of SonarQube 6.6, the problem seems to be fixed somehow. SonarQube Server is able to start now.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs point to an unexpected state, that should never appear. Either this is a bug in SonarQube, or something unexpected happened to your SonarQube installation.

I suggest these steps:

- Verify your [MD5 hash](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) of your download. If the checksum does not match, redownload.
- Unzip the downloaded zip file again.
- Start with a new, empty directory

Comment: No problem with MD5. I unzipped it to a new directory, but again the same failure.